# Mean of means with a subset

Tags: r, data.table

Imagine a data table

```
ID    Score
1     10
1     13
1     12
2     10
3     6
3     6
```

The average for user 1 is 11.67. The average for user 2 is 10. The average for user 3 is 6.

The UniqAverage I am looking for would be ((11.67+10+6)/3) =9.223`

For replication purposes feel free to use...

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame( ID=c(1,1,1,2,3,3), Score1=c(10,13,12,10,6,6) ) 
dt = data.table(df)
```

A previous question lead to me learning I could do

```
dt[, mean(Score1), ID][,mean(V1)]
```

To get this average of averages by ID.

However, what if I only wanted the mean of scores > 10?

So I'd wind up with

```
ID    V1
1     12.5
2     0
3     0
```

So my final result would be `4.167`

Attempts to use which failed.

```
dt[, mean( which(Score1) > 10 ), ID][,mean(V1)]
```

Comment: In most (if not all) cases computing an average of averages is ill advised. See http://ksrowell.com/blog-visualizing-data/2014/05/09/is-an-average-of-averages-accurate-hint-no/

Comment: Yup. This is much simpler than what I had.  I got it working now by doing dt[ dt[,Score1>10], mean(Score1), ID]

Comment: You can construct an example like `dt = data.table(...)`. No need to start with `df = data.frame(..)`.

Comment: Why `dt[ dt[,Score1>10], mean(Score1), ID]`? Why not `dt[Score1>10, mean(Score1), ID]`

Answer (score 2):

We can `join` on a dataset with `unique` 'ID' after getting the `mean` of 'Score1' by 'ID' where the "Score1" is greater than 10.

```
dt1 <- dt[Score1>10, .(V1= mean(Score1)), by = ID
          ][data.table(ID= unique(dt$ID)), on = "ID"][is.na(V1), V1 :=0][]
dt1
#   ID   V1
#1:  1 12.5
#2:  2  0.0
#3:  3  0.0

dt1[, mean(V1)]
#[1] 4.166667
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with base R and `aggregate`:

```
x <- aggregate(df, list(df$ID), function(x) mean(ifelse(x > 10, x, NA), na.rm = T))[,3]
mean(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
```

Comment: re last line `mean(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))`, I wouldn't be sure if mean 0 is expected value for further mean calculation. Might be better to replace it with mean of means calculated on non-NAs.

Comment: I think it follows the output Jibril wanted. For `ID` 2 and 3, there are no cases with `Score` > 10, and the 'mean' of these groups is 0.